# How do I make a process run real-time with raspberry pi PREEMPT_RT patch?

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi, real-time, rtos

I've patched my Raspbian OS with the PREEMPT_RT patch to make my OS preemptable. How do I make one of my applications run real-time? (Loadable Kernel Modules, etc.)

Comment: There might be some helpful info over at [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) such as this: [Is it possible to run real time software?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1408).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35766811/build-an-rt-application-using-preempt-rt

Comment: Reconsider your tags.  Why are Python or C relevant for example?

Answer (score 3):

Processes in Linux are already preemptable through round-robing time-slicing. What the PREEMPT_RT patch does is support *priority based* preemption.  That is the highest priority *ready* thread runs until it blocks or is preempted by a higher priority thread becoming *ready*.   Without PREEMPT_RT higher priority threads simply get allocated more and/or larger time slices. (Somewhat simplistic description - Linux scheduling is a little more sophisticated that that in practice).

A process does not magically become "real-time" by being run on a real-time OS or even PREEMPT_RT.  These simply provide real-time support - your application still has to be designed appropriately to meet real-time deadlines.  From [Real-time Linux Wiki FAQ](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Do_I_need_root_privileges_to_start_a_realtime_application.3F):

> A bad designed application on non-RT will never behave realtime on RT.

You can set the priority and scheduling policy of a existing process using [chrt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chrt.1.html).  But as explained, running a process at a high priority does not necessarily make it "real-time". The worst case will be that your process hogs the processor so that nothing else can run.